# Open a DNN (DotNetNuke) page in a new browser window

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

I use NavigateURL to redirect request to a new DNN logical page. What I would like to achieve is to open the new page in a separate browser window and be able to set the window dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a page in a new window must be done on the client side. You can do it by including target="_blank" in an http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

So after a button was clicked or whatever is supposed to trigger the open you would need to call some javascript to open your new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a new browser window with a server-side redirect.  You can only choose between 301 or 302 redirects from the server, both of which will redirect the current browsing session to the new location.  Indeed it is up to the browser how to handle a 301 or 302 - theoretically you could write a browser that ignored the 301 or 302, or that opened them in new windows.  However, convention dictates that all browsers behave in the same way.  The point being that you can't control browser behaviour from the server.

If you want to open a new page it needs to be done either with a "target=_new" attribute in an  link, or with javascript.